# json and jquery using this

Tags: jquery, json

I have an issue here:

I am trying to convert a jquery string that is obtained by `$this.text` into a json argument then output the results in an alert:

this is the json: `var test = { "hi" : { "Name":"moe", "Genre":"ez"} };`

`$this.text()` will have the text of "hi"
`alert(test.$this.text().Name)`

keep in mind replacing this.text with "hi" works great

I've tried so many this if anyone cant help in any way it would be appreciated very much

Comment: Please post few more lines of code to understand clearly. You are storing it in `var test`. What would `$this.text()` then?

Answer (score 0):

To return value from json using key name inside variable/function you should use square brackets. Like this :

```
var test = { "hi" : { "Name":"moe", "Genre":"ez"} };

// $this.text() - returns hi
alert(test[$this.text()].Name)
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L1bxqz7c/ Please check this fiddle, I cant predict how your functions work and how your project is setup, you will need to adapt your code. In fiddle you will see that it works

Answer (score 0):

Using like this:
`test[$this.text()].Name`

Comment: I tried:
`var test = { "hi" : { "Name":"moe", "Genre":"ez"} };
var text = 'hi';
test[text];//{Name: "moe", Genre: "ez"}`
Or you can try:
`test[$this.text()+''].Name`

Answer (score 0):

> $this.text() will have the text of "hi"

Above statement states that :

```js
var test = { "hi" : { "Name":"moe", "Genre":"ez"} };

function text() {
  return "hi";
}

console.log(test[text()]);
```

Hence, if you want to access Name property of **`hi`** object then try this :

```js
var test = { "hi" : { "Name":"moe", "Genre":"ez"} };

function text() {
  return "hi";
}

console.log(test[text()].Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed the json had to be placed in brackets and $this needed to be $(this)